# How can I get a file from the additional info in a woocommerce order in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to get the contents of a file contained (I presume) within a woocommerce order and while I'm familiar with PHP, I have no idea how to wordpress, so apologies if this has an obvious solution.

I added this additional field called `myfield2` for a file upload through WooCheckout. This file contains just a `json` object. There's another field called `myfield1` which is just a drop-down-selected string value and I'm getting that just fine.

Here's my closest punt at this:

```
<?PHP
$some_order_number = "869";
echo "<br>-----------------------------------<br>";
$order = get_post_meta( $some_order_number );
var_dump($order);
echo "<br>-----------------------------------<br>";
var_dump($order["myfield1"]);
echo "<br>-----------------------------------<br>";
var_dump($order["myfield2"]);
?>
```

What I see on the resulting page is:

```
array(47) { <...All the order details (name, address, ordered item etc)...> } 
"-----------------------------------------"
array(1) { [0]=> string(11) "Three times" } 
"-----------------------------------------"
array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "895," }
```

What do I do with this `"895,"` value? Is it an ID number that goes somewhere? Or am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: I don't know about a file, but you will/should probably use the Woo functions such as `$Order = wc_get_order( $order_id );` and `$Items = $Order->get_items();` and then loop on `$Items` and do something like this `$Item->get_product()->get_meta($key)` if that is in the products meta data etc.  You can also do `$Order->get_meta()` if it's in there.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix ok, I tried `wc_get_order` and it does give me a different style of object with teh same information as before. I can see that it contains `myfield2` as well with the same string value inside of it `"895,"`.

The field is attached to the order, not the items within the order. Looking into the array of items doesn't show me the information that I need.
`$Order->get_meta()` provides me with a blank string. I'll check out the woocommerce documentation, if they have their own function set.

Comment: You need to put the name of the metadata in there that you want.  From Woo's source code `public function get_meta( $key = '', $single = true, $context = 'view' )`  That is if it's in the metadata.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix Thank you. At least this was able to give me the extra field values the "proper" way. I tried using this `"895,"` as a key for `get_meta()` just in case but it came up empty. Nothing new out of `get_meta_data()` either.

Comment: Yea I don't know it may be part of the order itself, the best bet would be to look at the documentation for Order or the source code (that's what I do).  Unless someone else knows.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I managed to find the answer in their documentation. Thanks for pointing me the right way, man. Saved me a lot of time.

Comment: Glad you got it working, at the end of the day that's what matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trawling through WooCommerce's documentation, I found something that works! I cannot guarantee that this is the most efficient way of doing it, but it does the job.

```
<?PHP

// Get the file's field name
// Known as "abbreviation" on WooCheckout
$file_field_name = 'myfield2';

// Get the order number. (could use wc_get_orders() )
$order_id = "896";

// Get the order object for this order id
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

// Get the attachment ID.
$attachment_id = $order->get_meta($file_field_name);

// Get the properties of this attachment
$props = wc_get_product_attachment_props( $attachment_id );

// Select the URL from the properties
$file_url = $props["url"];

// Download the file data from this url.
$file_data = file_get_contents($file_url);

// ...now we do stuff with the file contents.
echo "file contents: <br>";
var_dump($file_data);

?>
```

..And here it is in a single function, for the copy&pasters.

```
/**
 * Given the order object and the file's field name,
 * get the file contents from the uploaded content.
 */
function get_order_file($order, $field_name){
    $attachment_id = $order->get_meta($field_name);
    $props = wc_get_product_attachment_props( $attachment_id );
    $file_data = file_get_contents($props["url"]);
    return $file_data;
}
```